# Move position scrollbar

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar

I need to move the position of the scrollbar in my page exactly like this [This is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znHZI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what is your target and what problem is making you stuck, attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried to solve the issues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do it with CSS. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-position-of-scrollbar-using-css/amp/ . Looking up “*Change position of scroll bar in HTML*” will give you plenty of solutions. I can’t give exact code because the question wasn’t very specific.